# How to include template generated in runtime and stored in variable?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

### Business:

Practical background for all that is design of web-app, where web-page constructed from prototype objects, gadgets, which individually defined each in its own `view` function (its own code, not necessarily django-view function). And to build a 'production' web-page they can be placed in regular view, related to this page, and produce web-page elements according to given source-data and other parameters.
For example I have a chart-gadget, and it receives source data, parameters, about chart-type, beauty/colors etc, and draws a chart. How can it be stored in separate from  specific ap, loose-coupled code? Which design-approach is better?

### What Ive tried:

Ive tried 'dumb' way:

For example I have a simple view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import Template, Context
from string import letters
def home(request):
    t = Template("""<ul>
                        {% for key, value in d.items %}
                            <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>""")
    d = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(letters)}
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'t': t, 'd':d})
```

And template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django tests</title>

</head>
<body>
{% include t with d=d %}
</body>
</html>
```

With such setup I get: `TemplateDoesNotExist`

### Expectations about answer:

Im searching any reasonable scheme for storing chunk of web-page, which designed to kinda live by its own life, less-or-more separately from other elements of web-page, in a similarly separate chunk of code in web-app program backend. 
As example I can provide such projects as:

- [iGoogle](http://www.google.com/ig)
- [Netvibes](http://www.netvibes.com/en)

### Thank you!

*ps*
**Extracts from django-docs:**

- [Extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#extends):

> {% extends variable %} uses the value of variable. If the variable
>   evaluates to a  string, Django will use that string as the name of the
>   parent template. *If the variable  evaluates to a Template object,
>   Django will use that object as the parent template.*

So It means, that with {% extends %} tag, operation what Im talking in question is definitely possible.

- [Include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include):

> This example includes the contents of the template whose name is
>   contained in the variable template_name:
>
> `{% include template_name %}`

So it probably means, that variable passed to `{% include %}` can bu just a string with name of file. And if its true, it is clear answer on my question - **template defined in variable cannot be included in regular template.**
It still slightly ambiguous for me, because in Python word `name` might be used as synonym of `variable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone already mentioned in a comment, you need to just render your template to a string and pass it in to the second template, marking it as a safe string so it isn't auto-escaped. So, your example would be:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from string import letters
def home(request):
    t = Template("""<ul>
                        {% for key, value in d.items %}
                            <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>""")
    c = Context({'d': {k: v for v, k in enumerate(letters)}})
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'t': mark_safe(t.render(c))})
```

Then, in home.html, render with `{{ t }}`

Answer (score 1):

You should put your include template in it's own file

include.html:

```
<ul>
    {% for key, value in d.items %}
        <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

home.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django tests</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include 'include.html' with d=d %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Then your view becomes:

```
def home(request):
    d = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(letters)}
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'d':d})
```

Comment: The goal is in using template defined in variable

Comment: You should probably just render your template and mark it as safe and use the template directly in the template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

Answer (score 1):

You should render your sub-template, then place it in the context of your `home.html` template (as `t` in this case).  This is what I've used before for recursive templates.

**home.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django tests</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ t }}
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import Template, Context
from string import letters

def home(request):
    t = Template("""<ul>
                        {% for key, value in d.items %}
                            <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>""")
    d = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(letters)}
    t_rendered = t.render(Context({'d': d}))
    return render_to_response('home.html',
                              {'t': t_rendered})
```

Note that you can cache your sub-template by creating it outside of the view so it doesn't get created on every request.  You can use `loader` to keep your sub-template in a template file.  However, changes will not reflect until you restart the server.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import Template, Context, loader
from string import letters

t = loader.get_template('subtemplate.html')

def home(request):
    d = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(letters)}
    t_rendered = t.render(Context({'d': d}))
    return render_to_response('home.html',
                              {'t': t_rendered})
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) is a shortcut operation.  I don't think it takes a template as 2nd param but a context instead

```
return render_to_response('home.html', {'d': d,})

<html>
<head>
    <title>Django tests</title>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
   {% for key, value in d.items %}
     <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}
   {% endfor %}
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Yo ucould create a list template in your template dir and include it in your template
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include
It looks like include just takes a template name and not a dynamic template